# MS Dynamics - Contract line not updating with Contract selection on Case(Incident)

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a synchronous plugin that will check for the Contract an account has and assign it to the Case when a new case is created, this plugin get the contract and the contract line, but it only shows the contract when i save the new incident, the contract line remains blank, i have to refresh the page to show the contract line.

I set both the Contract and the Contract line before asking my plugin to update the Case, the plugin is running ok, no failed message on the system job, when i debug it, both fields are valid, i think is something with the UI that is not displaying the information correctly/or not allowing to set both fields at the same time, how can i make it accept it?

Below you check my Execute code.

```
try
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            Incident incident = (Incident)entity.ToEntity<Incident>();
            incident = (Incident)service.Retrieve(Incident.EntityLogicalName, 
                incident.Id, new ColumnSet("customerid","subjectid"));

            Contract contract = checkForContract(incident.CustomerId.Id, service);
            if (contract != null)
            {
                Incident incidentToUpdate = new Incident();
                incidentToUpdate.IncidentId = incident.IncidentId;
                incidentToUpdate.ContractId = contract.ToEntityReference();

                ContractDetail contractLine = 
                    checkForContractLine(contract.Id, incident, service);

                if (contractLine != null)
                {
                    incidentToUpdate.ContractDetailId = contractLine.ToEntityReference();
                }
                service.Update(incidentToUpdate);
            }
        }
```